# asp.net C# API not properly receiving data on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, iis-7, http-post

I have an application sending a request to an API, this request works fine when running the API locally (through visual studio with the default iisexpress.exe)
However, when published and deployed to our IIS7 web server, it fails to receive data from the original application. Both required values are received as null.

Here is the (simplified) API code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveData(string data1, string data2)
{
    if (data1 == null || data2 == null)
    {
        Logger.log("Empty data. data1: {0}, data2: {1}.", data1, data2);
        return Json({ OK=0, message="Data not received" });
    }

    // Handling of saved data, won't be reached
}
```

The Logger class simply logs to a log file, confirming that the values are indeed both empty.

Here is the (also simplified) application code sending the request:

```
string data1 = "Data!";
string data2 = "More data!";

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

client.BaseAddress = new Uri(SERVER_URI);

MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
content.Add(new StringContent(data1), "data1");
content.Add(new StringContent(data2), "data2");

Logger.log("Sending data... data1: {0}, data2: {1}.", data1, data2);

HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("API/SaveData", content).Result;
```

So again, it works fine when the API is running local but not when it's running remote (it doesn't matter where the application runs, both places result in data1 and data2 being null). 
I'd say this implies that a server setting is wrong, but I cannot figure out which setting this would be.

Even weirder: When the same request is made directly to the API from Postman (chrome plugin) or a jQuery request, it works even with the API being on the server which would imply the opposite: The server is fine but my application is faulty.

I've tried messing around with the headers without success.

Comment: Are you getting any error? or is the issue is that -  the value being passed to api bcomes null?

Comment: The value passed to the API becomes null. Or better, the value passed isn't null but the value received is. No errors occur.

Comment: I have no idea of web api, but in web services this happens when there is a mismatch in service reference. Not sure if it is relavant here.. :(